# get only x.x.x from <version>x.x.x-SNAPSHOT</version> from this expression

Tags: xml, curl, awk, grep, cut

INPUT- cat my.txt

The version of the current file

```
<version>x.x.x-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Desired output:

```
x.x.x
```

(which are digits and dynamic values)

Tried multiple grep and awk commands but no luck.

Comment: Is it HTML or XML ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot It is XML file.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
xmllint --xpath '
    substring-before(//*[contains(text(), "-SNAPSHOT")]/text(), "-SNAPSHOT")
' file.xml
```

From a pipe:

```
curl -s 'http://example.com/query_string' |
    xmllint --xpath '
        substring-before(//*[contains(text(), "-SNAPSHOT")]/text(), "-SNAPSHOT")
' -
```

You can replace trailing `-` by `/dev/stdin`.

## Output

```
x.x.x
```

## Note

**Don't parse XML/HTML with regex, use a proper XML/HTML parser and a powerful [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query**.

You can use one of the following :

[xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) often installed by default with `libxml2-utils`, xpath1

[xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) can edit, select, transform... Not installed by default, xpath1

[xpath](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath) installed via perl's module XML::XPath, xpath1

[xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) xpath3

[saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) my own project, wrapper over @Michael Kay's Saxon-HE Java library, xpath3

#### or you can use high level languages and proper libs, I think of :

[python](/questions/tagged/python)'s [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) (`from lxml import etree`)

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod), [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath), [`XML::Twig::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig), [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)

[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) [nokogiri](/questions/tagged/nokogiri), [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-NokogiriXpath.rb.html)

[php](/questions/tagged/php) `DOMXpath`, [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-DOMXpath.php.html)

---

Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Could you please suggest any grep or awk commands, xmllint is not working for me

Comment: No, regex tools are not the way to parse XML. Which OS/distro/version ?

Comment: I am getting this as output of a curl command, i want to use pipe "|" grep or awk to cut the x.x.x as an output, Please suggest something similar command

Comment: I thought that was obvious, anyway, post edited accordingly